# Matching first set of elements with xpath

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I have an xml document that looks like this.

```
<foo>
    <bar type="artist"/> Bob Marley </bar>
    <bar type="artist"/> Peter Tosh </bar>
    <bar type="artist"/> Marlon Wayans </bar>
</foo>
<foo>
    <bar type="artist"/> Bob Marley </bar>
    <bar type="artist"/> Peter Tosh </bar>
    <bar type="artist"/> Marlon Wayans </bar>
</foo>
<foo>
    <bar type="artist"/> Bob Marley </bar>
    <bar type="artist"/> Peter Tosh </bar>
    <bar type="artist"/> Marlon Wayans </bar>
</foo>
```

I would like to construct an xpath that returns only the first set:

```
<bar type="artist"/> Bob Marley </a>
<bar type="artist"/> Peter Tosh </a>
<bar type="artist"/> Marlon Wayans </a>
```

How would one go about this? I have tried `//bar[@type='artist']` but it's obvious there's more to this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For the example did you mean to close the <bar> tags with </a> or was that just a typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get only sub elements of some "indexed" node:

```
//foo[1]/bar[@type='artist']
```

Exmaple in C#:

```
string xml =
    @"<root>
        <foo>
            <bar type='artist'> Artist 1 </bar>
            <bar type='artist'> Artist 2 </bar>
            <bar type='artist'> Artist 3 </bar>
        </foo>
        <foo>
            <bar type='artist'> Artist 1 </bar>
            <bar type='artist'> Artist 2 </bar>
            <bar type='artist'> Artist 3 </bar>
            <bar type='artist'> Artist 4 </bar>
        </foo>
    </root>";
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.LoadXml(xml);

Assert.That(document.SelectNodes(@"/root/foo[1]/bar[@type='artist']").Count,
                                 Is.EqualTo(3));
Assert.That(document.SelectNodes(@"//foo[1]/bar[@type='artist']").Count,
                                 Is.EqualTo(3));
```

Comment: Thanks Elisha. This looks close to what I need. Will try it out later. BTW, I'm working with pythons lxml so will have to adapt this a bit.